# "Remember your lunch/lunches"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

A mother has lined lunch boxes up on the breakfast bar. Her three kids are about to head out the door without them, so she says:

> Remember your lunch./Remember your lunches.

Question:

If there is one lunch box for each kid, should it be "lunch" or "lunches"? My guess is "lunch", is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know the subject of the sentence.   Alas, English makes that difficult if not impossible.

The original sentence is an imperative, with an imperative's typical implicit subject.  We know that it's second-person, but we don't know the grammatical number.  We wouldn't even know that number if we added the word "you" as an explicit subject, because the singular "thou" is obsolete.

A direct address might help.  Or, it might just confuse things:

> Each of you, remember your lunch.
> Hey you guys, remember your lunches.

Instead of finding one particular answer, we've found support for both options.

Pick whichever you like.

Answer (score -2):

Well I mean since you said boxes. The correct way of putting that would be Don't forget your lunch boxes. Otherwise Yea lunch is fine.

There is also a grammatical wrong way of saying it....like when people say guys's. Like your guys´s lunch. It's wrong but used nonetheless.

Comment: "Like your guys´s lunch." this is very bad English.

Comment: I literally said it's grammatically wrong. Twice. However it is still used when speaking informally.

Comment: It was the `your guys's` I noticed. That's written, not spoken. Did you mean `you guys' lunch` ?